# trouble running samirax model with seasonality as 288

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, arima, sarimax

My time series has a frequency of 5 minutes, and every 24 hours it has a seasonality so s=288. I tried to run SARIMAX with s=288, but it's too big and the computer can't hold it up. Is there other ways to get this seasonality counted while running an model?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a53kD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2jTv.png)

the orders are as below.

```
sarima_order = (11,1,1)  
seasonal_order=(6,0,0,228)
```

Comment: Could you please explain what 'it's too big and the computer can't hold it up' means? Are you getting an error? If so, please post what that error is.